How to filter SQLAlchemy dynamic field?
I'm working with SQLAlchemy in a FastAPI application, and I'm trying to implement a dynamic calculation for a field called distance_to in my User model. The goal is to filter users based on this dynamically calculated distance, but it seems the filtering doesn't work because the field behaves as if it doesn't exist in the model.
When add to request filtering by **distance_to__lt ** i get NULL < ? in my query.
 WHERE "user_id = ?) AS anon_2)) AND NULL < ? ORDER BY user.first_name ASC
I have a custom filter class defined as follows:
from fastapi_filter.contrib.sqlalchemy import Filter

class UserFilter(Filter):
    # Other fields...

    distance_to__lt: Optional[float] = None
    order_by: list[str] = ['first_name']

    class Constants(Filter.Constants):
        model = User

user model
from sqlalchemy.orm import query_expression

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    # Other fields...

    distance_to: Mapped[float] = query_expression()

CRUD
from sqlalchemy.orm import with_expression

async def get_users(
    session: AsyncSession, user_filter: UserFilter, current_user: User
):
    query = (
        select(User)
        .join(User.location)
        .options(
            with_expression(
                User.distance_to,
                "some_calculation depending on current_user"
            ),
        )
    )
    query = user_filter.filter(query)
    query = user_filter.sort(query)

How can I ensure that the distance_to field is recognized in the filtering process?
Is there a way to dynamically calculate and filter based on distance_to without encountering this issue?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

The mapped attribute cannot be applied to other parts of the query, such as the WHERE clause, the ORDER BY clause, and make use of the ad-hoc expression; that is, this won’t work:
can't refer to A.expr elsewhere in the query
stmt = (
    select(A)
    .options(with_expression(A.expr, A.x + A.y))
    .filter(A.expr > 5)
    .order_by(A.expr)
)

The A.expr expression will resolve to NULL in the above WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause. To use the expression throughout the query, assign to a variable and use that:
assign desired expression up front, then refer to that in the query
a_expr = A.x + A.y
stmt = (
    select(A)
    .options(with_expression(A.expr, a_expr))
    .filter(a_expr > 5)
    .order_by(a_expr)
)

reference: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/columns.html#orm-queryguide-with-expression
